# How to take away fraction part using String.Format (c#)

Tags: c#, string.format

How to take away fraction part while formatting decimal type in C#?

```
        decimal a = 1.00m;

        String.Format("{0}", a); // result is 1.00 Should be 1, HOW?
```

Comment: `decimal a = 1.00;` should not compile. Is your question about appended zero digits only (as in the difference between `"3.14000"` and `"3.14"`), or do you want to also round numbers that have too many non-zero decimals?

Comment: Correct, I think the first line has to be `decimal a = 1.00m;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
String.Format("{0:N0}", a); // "1"
```

Or, to display 1 decimal point:

```
String.Format("{0:N1}", a); // "1.0"
```

More info on [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Comment: Note the difference between `N0` (`N1`) and `F0` (`F1`). Use the `N` if you require thousands separators in large numbers, as in `"87,654,321"`.

Answer (score 4):

You could always [Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh.aspx) it:

```
String.Format("{0}", Math.Floor(a));
```

Or, since there's nothing else in this `Format` line, just go this way:

```
Math.Floor(a).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String.Format("{0:0}", a);
```

read more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx